# Cannot connect IoT Hub using X509 CA certificate by mosquitto, paho

Tags: azure, ssl, iot, x509certificate, mosquitto

thank you for the great document. and tutorials.
I am still stack in connecting IoT Hub using mosquitto. I guess I set all of the option written here as clientId, Username, topic name. Are there any additional option should I add? thanks for your help!

```
$ openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
$ openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
$ # Upload rootCA.pem to IoT Hub and get verification code
$ openssl genrsa -out verificationCert.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key verificationCert.key -out verificationCert.csr
# create csr with CN=[verification code]
$ openssl x509 -req -in verificationCert.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out verificationCert.pem -days 500 -sha256
$ # upload verificationCert.pem and pass verificaton
$ openssl genrsa -out deviceCert.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -in deviceCert.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out deviceCert.pem -days 500 -sha256
$ # create Device in IoT Hub
$ mosquitto_pub -d -h $myhub.azure-devices.net -p 8883 --cafile /etc/ssl/certs/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem --cert ./deviceCert.pem --key ./deviceCert.key -i $mydevice -u "$myhub.azure-devices.net/$mydevice/?api-version=2018-06-30" -t "/devices/$mydevice/messages/events/" -m '{"message": "Hello IoT Hub!"}'
Client [deviceName] sending CONNECT
Error: The connection was lost.
```

I also failed by paho.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#tlsssl-configuration
my code is following.

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl

path_to_root_cert = "/etc/ssl/certs/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem"
device_id = "mydevice"
iot_hub_name = "myhub"


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("Device sent message")


client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish

# Set the username but not the password on your client
client.username_pw_set(username=iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net/" +
                       device_id + "/?api-version=2018-06-30", password=None)

# Set the certificate and key paths on your client
cert_file = "./deviceCert.pem"
key_file = "./deviceCert.key"
client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=cert_file, keyfile=key_file,
               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=None)

# Connect as before
client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883)

client.publish("devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/", "{id=123}", qos=1)
client.loop_forever()
```

the result was following which means unauthorized.

```
Device connected with result code: 5
Device disconnected with result code: 5
```

JFYI, I could connect to AWS IoT using own CA cert by following step

```
$ openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
$ openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
$ openssl genrsa -out verificationCert.key 2048
$ aws iot get-registration-code  
$ openssl req -new -key verificationCert.key -out verificationCert.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -in verificationCert.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out verificationCert.pem -days 500 -sha256
$ # use the registration code as CN
$ aws iot register-ca-certificate --ca-certificate file://rootCA.pem --verification-cert file://verificationCert.pem  
$ aws iot update-ca-certificate --certificate-id [id which got above] --new-status ACTIVE  
$ openssl genrsa -out deviceCert.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -in deviceCert.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out deviceCert.pem -days 500 -sha256
$ aws iot register-certificate --certificate-pem file://deviceCert.pem --ca-certificate-pem file://rootCA.pem  
$ aws iot update-certificate --certificate-id [id which got above] --new-status ACTIVE  
$ mosquitto_pub -h [endpoint].iot.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com -p 8883 --cafile ./rootCA.pem --cert ./deviceCert.pem --key ./deviceCert.key -q 1 -d -t topic/test -i testdevice -m "Hello, World"
$ # rootCA is the CA I've got from https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can connect just fine with `mosquitto_pub`, using the exact same steps as you to create the various keypairs. Note that you have a mistake in the topic, it should not start with a `/` (for your Paho sample, you got it right though).
A few things you should check:

- can you confirm you provisioned your device in IoT hub as X.509 CA Signed, and not "self-signed"?
- CN for your device cert should not contain special characters or white space, and you should use the exact same name (your `$mydevice` variable) as the Device ID to create the "X.509 CA Signed" device in your IoT Hub.

Comment: Thanks kartben, Your advice is super helpful.
Yes, indeed I didn't put device ID to Common Name for rootCA.pem. When I put it, I succeed to send message from Paho.
Now I think I am getting close to the goal. Do you have any idea from the output below...?

To answer your first check, yes I provisioned the device as X.509 CA signed.

Comment: ```
$ mosquitto_pub -d -h ${myhub}.azure-devices.net -p 8883 --cafile /etc/ssl/certs/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem --cert ./deviceCert.pem --key ./deviceCert.key -i ${mydevice} -u "${myhub}.azure-devices.net/${mydevice}/?api-version=2018-06-30" -t "devices/${mydevice}/messages/events/" -m '{"message": "Hello IoT Hub!"}'



Client mick sending CONNECT
Error: The connection was lost.

$ python3 ./paho_azure.py 
Device connected with result code: 0
Device sent message
```

Comment: Finally, I succeed in mosquito_pub by adding MQTT version.
`mosquitto_pub -d -h ${myhub}.azure-devices.net -p 8883 --cafile /etc/ssl/certs/Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem --cert ./deviceCert.pem --key ./deviceCert.key -i ${mydevice} -u "${myhub}.azure-devices.net/${mydevice}/?api-version=2018-06-30" -t "devices/${mydevice}/messages/events/" -m '{"message": "Hello IoT Hub!"}' -V mqttv311`

It is interesting that I thought default version was v311. FYI, my mosquitto_pub version is 1.4.15.

Anyway, Thank you so much for your advice!!

Comment: mosquitto_pub 1.4.15 is a fairly old version, or at least old enough that it defaults to mqttv31, so that definitely was the root cause, I think! Glad you got this working.

Note that in your first comment you are indicating you used deviceId for the CN of rootCA.pem, but I am assuming you meant deviceCert.pem?

Comment: > Note that in your first comment you are indicating you used deviceId for the CN of rootCA.pem, but I am assuming you meant deviceCert.pem?
Correct. I meant deviceCert.pem. I put deviceId for CN of deviceCert.pem when `openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr`

Comment: I have the similar issue with the mosquitto with azure dps. Here is my cli mosquitto_pub -d -h ${MyDPS}.azure-devices-provisioning.net -p 8883 --cafile /home/ubuntu/RND/edge/azure-connect/certs/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem --cert ./certs/dev1-full-chain.cert.pem --key ./certs/dev1.key.pem -i mqttpkj -u "${IDSCOPE}/registrations/dev1/api-version=2019-03-31"  -t "$dps/registrations/PUT/iotdps-register/?$rid=1" -m "{\"registrationId\":\"dev1\"}" --tls-version t
lsv1.2 -V mqttv311. I get connection refused: Not authorized error